# How can I initiate in VS Code to compile coffeescripts to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, coffeescript, visual-studio-code

I have a node.js project in Visual Studio Code (Win 10), and it's there a server.coffee from another IDE. The compiled server.js too exists, and it runs fine (in vs code too).
But now I want to change the server.coffee, and it's no way to compile it to the JavaScript file. It should happen at Ctrl-S - how can I do this? There is no extension or so...

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl-Shift-B`?

Comment: Thank you. This little tip has given me impulse to find the solution :)

Comment: Thats a solution:

Write in package.json:
       "bin": {
            "coffee": "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee",
            "cake": "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "prepublish": "coffee -o lib -c server.coffee"
        } 
The "scripts" know the compile instruction, and the "bin" makes the pathes correct (look for your situation). For doing the compilation press F1 and give "npm install". Would be much better if runs automatically - may be we find a solution.

Comment: Look to the launch.json too. You must set in "configurations" another path.

       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/lib/server.js"
because there is saved the js-file.

Comment: If you do come up with a solution, think about putting it in as an answer to your question. I am sure many will find value in it.